# Force unmount drive - Yosemite

Tags: macos

have a very stubborn Mac, it is a slightly older model but can run Yosemite. I have been trying all day to reformat the main drive in it, I have using the regular disk utility and terminal. I have tried for un-mounting and reformatting but nothing is working. I have narrowed it down to the recovery volume on the drive that refuses to unmount. Is there a way to run in recovery mode without using the hard drive? Because as of right now I have no way of reformatting the drive. As, ironically is seems that the recovery partition is blocking me from doing it. Any suggestions on how to get this sucker to comply?

I want to: Reformat the main drive completely It seems every partition but the recovery is complying

Comment: When you try to format where is OS X being loaded from?

Comment: If you've booted from the Recovery HD from the local internal HDD/SSD you cannot then unmount and reformat the Recovery HD because it's in use!  If you want to completely reformat the entire internal HDD/SSD then you need to boot the Mac from a external source, e.g. a USB Installer made using the "/Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" command.  From there you can use Disk Utility to preform the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't completely reformat/erase/repartition the drive you are booting from (assuming you are booting from the recovery partition on your main disk drive).

So boot to a bootable DVD, a second (external) hard drive, a bootable thumb drive or boot to [Internet Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while starting your Mac.

Then open Disk Utility and reformat the internal drive.